# What's the best recourse when hibernate/HQL is too limited?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

If there's an operation I'd like to do on a mapped class, but is not currently supported by hibernate or HQL - what is the best fallback? Raw JDBC?

Or can I somehow leverage the existing mappings I have, to free me from writing boilerplate code, but still giving me more flexibility than is built into hibernate?

(This question does not talk about alternatives to hibernate - it assumes we are using hibernate as our main ORM)

Comment: I wouldn't want to go into specifics, btw - this is a general question, not about any specific operation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I'd say the best fallback is raw jdbc or even Oracle PL/SQL functions (or equivalents).

For sure it's much easier to understand a special call to raw jdbc than some very complicated java code to extend Hibernate.

I worked on a project in which the "Architect" used a lot of custom annotations and modified Hibernate to support his idea of a "perfect" ORM... Ultimately he was fired and all the crap removed because nobody else was able to make it work.